# Test case: Various files: Wrong answer

Tags: php

I was trying a problem on Testdome, in which we have to implement a `groupByOwners` method for example for the given input

for associative array `["Input.txt" => "Randy", "Code.py" => "Stan", "Output.txt" => "Randy"]`
*the groupByOwners function should return `["Randy" => ["Input.txt", "Output.txt"], "Stan" => ["Code.py"]]`

The code which I created has been run successfully but one of the tests were failing. I'm not able to figure out it. The site has given no clue also.

```
class FileOwners
{
    public static function groupByOwners($files)
    {
        $keys = FileOwners::pullKeys($files);
        $final_arr = [];
        for ($i=0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {
          # code...
          $result = FileOwners::pullValues($files, $keys[$i]);
          $final_arr[$keys[$i]] = $result;

        }
        return $final_arr;
    }
    private static function pullKeys($array)
    {
      $keys = [];
      foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        # code...
        $keys[] = $value;

      }
      return array_unique($keys);
    }
    private static function pullValues($array, $key)
    {
      $data = [];
      foreach ($array as $k => $value) {
        # code...
        if($value == $key) {
          $data[] = $k;
        }

      }
      return $data;
    }
}

$files = array
(
    "Input.txt" => "Randy",
    "Code.py" => "Stan",
    "Output.txt" => "Randy",
    "test.py" => "Stan"
);
var_dump(FileOwners::groupByOwners($files));
```

This was the code created by me. The sample output was correct. But the test case below was wrong.

**Various files: Wrong answer** This test was failing. What's the wrong with the code?
 Please have a look at the link of the same
https://www.testdome.com/d/php-interview-questions/5

You can try my code and see the results. Also below is the screen shot of the same.

[image]

Comment: It will be better if one could explain why down voted.

Comment: What does `Various files: Wrong answer ` mean? Is this a message that you are getting?

Comment: @Mawg please see the link added. I have no idea what they meant.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem (is that good news, or bad?). When I pasted your code into that link & ran it, I got "Run OK


array(2) { 
  ["Randy"]=> 
  array(2) { 
    [0]=> 
    string(9) "Input.txt" 
    [1]=> 
    string(10) "Output.txt" 
  } 
  ["Stan"]=> 
  array(2) { 
    [0]=> 
    string(7) "Code.py" 
    [1]=> 
    string(7) "test.py" 
  } 
} 
Your score is 67%, nice!"

Comment: It will run 3 test cases. All of them were success?

Comment: I see 4 test questions on that page. Your question only addresses the first, so I don't now what you mean by "3 test cases". I report only what happened when I ran #1 with your code

Comment: Please check the screen shot attached. Your score is also 67% because one of the test has failed.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now! But the first point says that you returned the correct answer - which contradicts the 3rd point.  Can you contact testdome and ask them to explain? In any case, you have now added enough info to this question that others should be able to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code fails because `array_unique` preservers element keys. So if you run with following data

```
$files = array
(
    "Input.txt" => "Randy",
    "Output.txt" => "Randy",
    "test.py" => "Stan",
);
```

You'll get the following array

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
     string(5) "Randy"
  [2]=>
     string(4) "Stan"
  }
```

Notice how the index of "Stan" value is still 2. You can run this example and see for yourself that it doesn't work for "Stan".
To fix this you need to reset the numbering in your array. The simplest way would be to call `array_values` function on your `$keys` array like so

```
return array_values(array_unique($keys));
```

Hope I was clear enough and this helps.

Comment: Perfect. Missed attention to details.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

```
class FileOwners
{
    public static function groupByOwners($files)
    {
        $res = [];
        foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
            $res[$value][] = $key;
        }
        return $res;
    }
}

$files = array
(
    "Input.txt" => "Randy",
    "Code.py" => "Stan",
    "Output.txt" => "Randy"
);
var_dump(FileOwners::groupByOwners($files));
```

Comment: simple array $key => $val swapping